# Constructor for structs referring to other structs in C

Tags: c, struct, constructor

I'm new to C. In my header file, I have two structs. One is built out of the other.

#### mylist.h:

```
#pragma once        
struct Node {
      void* data;
      struct Node *next;
};

typedef struct Node node;

struct List {
    Node* top;
};
typedef struct List* list;
```

I am trying to build the constructor. I have:

```
#include "mylist.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static node data; 
static list l; 
stack newlist(){
    l->top->data = NULL;
    return l;
}
```

In Main I call the constructor like so:

```
int main(){
    list m;
    m = newlist();
}
```

but it never gets to main. I get a seg fault immediately. I don't understand why; I'm accessing the content through the stack. Do I need to allocate space for the list first? I don't use the dot operator because the list is a pointer.

Comment: `static list l` reserves space for a pointer, but that pointer is initially `NULL`. So yes, you do need to allocate space for the structure.

Comment: You also do not have your `typedef` at the *beginning* of your declarations.

Comment: How do you know it never gets to `main`?

Comment: so first I would...
list new list(){
list l;
l  = malloc(sizeof(l));
l->top = NULL;
return l;
}

Comment: Post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Your code example is not even close to compilable.  At least cut-n-paste your actual code that compiles and gives the seg fault.

Comment: @tkausl `l` being null is more of a problem. Another problem is that `newlist` returns `stack` which is not defined. Also, using a pointer typedef for `list` makes the code more confusing.

Comment: Note that even after multiple missing semicolons have been added, you still have a problem in pure C that you've defined a type `node` but not a type `Node` — a C++ compiler won't have any problem, though (but a C++ compiler is not a C compiler).

Comment: When you say "it doesn't get into `main()`", how do you know that?  Have you run the code under a debugger?  Is it the first statement in `main()` (the call to `newlist()`) that doesn't complete?  That's different — it isn't called until after the code has entered `main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for `l` first. This is because `list` is a typedef of a pointer to a structure. Therefore, when you first declare `l`, it is just a pointer, pointing at invalid memory. Try the modification below:

```
list newlist(){
    list l;
    l = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    if (!l) {
        printf ("Error allocating memory (l)\n");
    } else {
        l->top = malloc (sizeof(struct Node));
        if (l->top) {
            l->top->data = NULL;
            return l;
        } else {
            // On failure to allocate top free memory and return NULL
            printf ("Error allocating memory (top)\n");
            free(l);
            l = NULL;  
        }
    }
    return l;
}
```

Note that the `static list l` moved inside of the function. You don't need the other static global `data` (Unless you use that in another part of the code not shown, in which case I would rename it to something else to avoid confusion with staruct member names).

You will need to include `<stdlib.h>` and `<stdio.h>` if you don't have them already.

Also, your struct definitions need a few corrections, for instance

```
struct Node {
    void* data;
    struct Node *next;
};
typedef struct Node node;

struct List {
    node* top;
};
typedef struct List* list;
```

Comment: Does every new node needs memory to be allocated for it. Will every call to push( int x) allocate memory space for x?

Where do I de-allocate memory? Do I deallocate all temp variables in the event of failure?

Comment: @kirk It depends. If the you are using a pointer to a node (as in `Node* top;` in your struct), that pointer is initially pointing at invalid memory, you need to allocate space for that node. If you use a node directly (as in `Node otherNode;`), otherNode is a variable in the stack (or heap depending on where you declared it) that has memory allocated for it at declaration time. I might not be understanding the other part of your question, or part of your code is not shown. I don't know what `push()` does.

Comment: Excuse me, I was thinking ahead. If I were building a stack out of structs, and I needed to push a new value on, I would allocate memory for that value.

Comment: No problem, I was owndering if I misread something. If you are going to store that in `Node.data`, since data is a pointer, you would definitely need to allocate memory for it before storing the value. If you know that data is going to be int, you might want to just declare a plain int in the structure to avoid allocation. Since you are using `void *` my guess is that you want to be able to store different types of data, in which case you will have to live will dynamic allocation.